# Prove convergence of the sequence $(z_1+z_2+\cdots + z_n)/n$ of Cesaro means

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, cesaro-summable

Prove that if $\lim_{n \to \infty}z_{n}=A$ then:
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{z_{1}+z_{2}+\cdots + z_{n}}{n}=A$$
I was thinking spliting it in: $$(z_{1}+z_{2}+\cdots+z_{N-1})+(z_{N}+z_{N+1}+\cdots+z_{n})$$
where $N$ is value of $n$ for which $|A-z_{n}|<\epsilon$
then taking the limit of this sum devided by $n$ , and noting that the second sum is as close as you wish to $nA$ while the first is as close as you wish to $0$. Not sure if this helps....

Comment: Possibly easier to first show for $A=0$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I edited the question, adding my idea. Could you tell me what you think, please?

Comment: Changed the title. There is no *series* here.

Comment: Maybe this question was asked here before (I did not search), but at least I remember that we had questions such that this can be obtained as a consequence of the results from those questions, see, e.g.,
[If $\sigma_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n}{n}$ then $\limsup\sigma_n \leq \limsup s_n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193157/if-sigma-n-fracs-1s-2-cdotss-nn-then-operatornamelim-sup-sigma)
and [limit of quotient of two series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100338/limit-of-quotient-of-two-series).

Comment: Here is yet another more general question: [Limit of a sequence in a vector normed space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/limit-of-a-sequence-in-a-vector-normed-space).

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that this is often called [Cesaro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean).

Comment: You might also be interested in the first problem in this problem set from MIT OCW: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-100c-real-analysis-fall-2012/assignments/MIT18_100CF12_ps5.pdf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like Homework problem, hence I'll just give hint:
$$\frac{z_1+z_2+\cdots +z_n}{n}-A=\frac {(z_1-A)+(z_2-A)+\cdots +(z_n-A)}{n}$$
Now use the defn of limit that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $|z_m-A| < \epsilon \ \forall m \geq N_0$

Also remember triangle inequality : $|a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n| \leq |a_1| + |a_2| +\cdots +|a_n|$

Can you find proper $a_i$ in terms of say $z_i$'s??

Comment: thankyou for help. It's not homework. Would $a_{i}$ be  $\frac{z_{i}}{n}$, and since for $n \to\infty $all sums go to $0$, it would be proved? @TheJoker

Comment: and would my first idea be wrong?

Comment: You can take $a_i=\frac{z_1-A}{n}$. Now use the fact that limit of $z_i$ is $A$. about your approach,it is true,just write rigorously :-).also there is **no** dofference between mine and your approach as your next step would be same.

Answer (score 15):

Let $\epsilon >0$

We have that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z_n=A$ thus $\exists n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|z_n-A|< \epsilon, \forall n \geqslant n_1$

$|\frac{z_1+...+z_n}{n}-A|=|\frac{(z_1-A)+...(z_{n_1-1}-A)}{n}+\frac{(z_{n_1}-A)+...+(z_n-A)}{n}| \leqslant \frac{|z_1-A|+...+|z_{n_1-1}-A|}{n}+ \frac{|z_{n_1}-A|+...+|z_n-A|}{n}$

Exists $n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$, by Archimedean property, such that $$\frac{|z_1-A|+...+|z_{n_1-1}-A|}{n}< \epsilon, \forall n \geqslant n_2$$

Now for $n \geqslant n_0= \max\{n_1,n_2\}$

$|\frac{z_1+...+z_n}{n}-A| \leqslant \epsilon+ \frac{(n-n_1) }{n}\epsilon<2 \epsilon $

Comment: Thanks for your answer; could you please explain why 'there exists $n_2$ such that...'

Comment: Because the numerator is a positive constant number and we use the Archimedean property of the real numbers(or you can see it as the convergence of $1/n$ to zero)

Answer (score 5):

This can be an easy consequence of a more general statement which is from Polya's *Problems and Theorems in Analysis*:

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a real sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$. And we have a family of finite sequences $\{\{b_{nm}\}_{m=1}^{m=n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$:
>   $$
> b_{11}\\
> b_{21},b_{22}\\
> b_{31},b_{32},b_{33}\\
> \cdots
> $$
>   such that
>   $$
> b_{mn}\geq 0
> $$
>   for all $m,n$,
>   and $\sum_{m}b_{nm}=1$ for each $n=1,2,\cdots$. Let $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be such that
>   $$
> c_n=\sum_{m=1}^na_mb_{nm}
> $$
>   Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=a$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{nm}=0$ for each $m$.

The question in OP is a special case of the statement by letting 
$$
b_{nm}=\frac{1}{n},\quad m=1,2,\cdots.
$$