# Convergence of series implies convergence of Cesaro Mean.

Tags: sequences-and-series, cesaro-summable

*Proof*.  Let $\sum_{k = 0}^N c_k \rightarrow s$, let $\sigma_N = (S_0 + \dots + S_{N-1})/N$ be the $Nth$ Cesaro sum where $S_K$ is the $Kth$ partial sum of the series.  Then $s - \sigma_N \\= s - c_0 - c_1(N-1)/N + c_2(N-2)N +\dots+c_{N-1}/N \\ =c_1/N + c_2 2/N + \dots + c_{N-1}(N-1)/N + c_N + \dots$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: As soon as you realize that convergence of a series is the same thing as convergence of the partial sums, it is the same question as asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means). (Several other questions about the same thing are linked there, too.)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You don't need the fact that it's a series, which is maybe why this is confusing for you.

Suppose $S_n \to S$ is a converging sequence. Then $\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n S_k \to S$ also. Roughly speaking, if you take $n$ large enough, then all the big terms (big index, not big in value) are close to $S$ ; all the small terms (small index) will get killed when $n$ goes to infinity.

Non-roughly speaking, 
$$
\left| \left( \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n S_k \right) - S \right| = \frac 1n \left| \sum_{k=1}^n (S_k - S) \right| \le \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n |S_k - S| = \frac {\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} |S_k - S|}{n} + \frac {\sum_{k=\ell+1}^n |S_k - S|}{n}
$$
Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and choose $\ell$ such that for all $k > \ell$, $|S_k - S| < \varepsilon/2$ by convergence of $S_k$ to $S$. Now that $\ell$ is fixed, choose $N$ large enough so that for all $n > N$, 
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} |S_k - S|}{n} < \varepsilon / 2.
$$
(Note that the numerator does not depend on $n$ so we still have freedom.) It follows that for all $n > N$,
$$
\frac {\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} |S_k - S|}{n} + \frac {\sum_{k=\ell+1}^n |S_k - S|}{n} \le \frac {\sum_{k=1}^{\ell} |S_k - S|}{n} + \frac{(n-\ell) (\varepsilon/2)}n  \le \varepsilon.
$$
For your particular problem, put $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Yeah, that does help.  Neat trick!

Comment: @Enjoys Math : I want to add : understanding the "roughly speaking" part is what's gonna make you a better "idea-producer". Understanding the other part is going to make you a better "proof-maker". You need both to become an amazing mathematician.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva if the series diverges it implies that $\sigma_N$ diverges ?

Comment: @Maman : No, just consider $\sum_{n \ge 1} (-1)^n$, which is a divergent series since the sequence $S_n$ is equal to $\frac{(-1)^n-1}2$, so $\sigma_N = \frac 1N \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{(-1)^n-1}2 \to \frac 12$. The Césarò mean averages out your sequence, so if your sequence keeps oscillating the mean is going to converge somewhere between the $\liminf$ and the $\limsup$. If $S_n$ grows to infinity however, $\sigma_N$ can diverge. I didn't think of a case where $S_n$ grows to infinity and $\sigma_N$ converges ; this could probably be figured out (if it's true or false) with some thinking.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva:  In the very beginning of the rigorous part of your proof, going from the left-hand side to the right-hand side of the first equality, would it not in fact be $\dfrac{1}{n}\Bigg|{\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(S_{k}-nS)}}\Bigg|$, and shouldn't that which follows contain the multiple $nS$ inside the sum of absolute values? My apologies if I missed something somewhere, if I'm incorrect, etc., but I was curious in this regard.

Comment: @Procore : there is no mistake in what I wrote. For $n=2$ for instance, $\frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^2 (S_k-S) = \frac 12 ( (S_1 - S) + (S_2 - S) ) = \frac {S_1 + S_2}2 - S. Essentially I wrote $-S = -nS/n and pulled one $-S/n$ in the sum for each $k$ and then factored $1/n$ out.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I see what you mean. See my comment for my apology in advance.

Comment: @Procore : Sorry if I sounded rude! This is totally okay. This forum exists for everyone to have doubts and for everyone else to clear these doubts!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva:  No - no rudeness whatsoever on your part, and no need to apologize.  I'm kicking myself for neglecting to hash through the notation. If anything, I knew I had to have missed something somewhere.  I appreciate the consideration - overall, your proof is very concise and elegant (concerning the rigorous part); I proved it differently using the $nS$ multiple instead which made things a little more tedious on my end, and, while I was comparing, I noticed the difference up front. No worries, and thank you for setting me straight.

Comment: @Procore : you didn't prove it "differently", you just added steps that I omitted. Writing $S = \frac{nS}n = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n S$ is the blank you want to fill.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: It's funny you mention that - right after I wrote my comment I was going to add that virtually everything is the same, I just used the word "different" to quickly implicate that I simply worked through some "additional" details that are covered more concisely in both of your estimates (regarding convergence of the given series and the overall Cesaro summability). It was a quick attempt at, "saving face" if you will. I'd post my answer, but it is part of homework that I have to finish (fortunately it is TeX'ed, but I'm not sure I have time - plus it is overkill at this point).

Comment: @Procore : Just let it go and get your homework done! ;)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva:  OK. Not sure what I'm letting go. Have a nice life.

Comment: @Procore : Letting go of posting your answer ;) if we have the same proof don't bother posting it!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Isn't there an implicit assumption in your proof that the chosen $l$ is $<n$? (i.e., what if for the given $n$ you have that the $l$ from which $|S_k-S|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is actually larger than $n$?). Doesn't this actually require using another threshold $N'$ and taking $\max\{N,N'\}$? Regardless, great proof :)

Comment: @Anon Actually the argument is still correct if $\ell > n$ but it makes things awkward and requiring explanation. But I did say "choose $N$ large enough", so I guess that since $\ell$ is fixed, you could take $\max \{N,\ell\}$, but it wouldn't affect the argument if you just removed terms that would disappear if $\ell > n$.