# Show that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_Sf(x,t)=\int_S\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)$ for each $t\in I$ when $S$ is a fixed integrable set.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, riemann-integration

Let be $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ a fixed integrable set and let be $f(x,t)$ scalar function of class $C^1$  defined in $S\times I$ where $I$ is an interval. So I ask to prove that the identity
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_Sf(x,t)=\int_S\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)
$$
holds fore each $t\in I$. So to prove it I advanced the following argumentations. First of all thorugh the linearly if integral **(is this correct?)** I observed that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_Sf(x,t):=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{\int_S f(x,t)-\int_Sf(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{\int_S\big(f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)\big)}{t-t_0}=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\int_S\Biggl(\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}\Biggl)
$$
for each $t_0\in I$ and so the statement follows directely showing that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\int_S\Biggl(\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}\Biggl)=\int_S\Biggl(\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}\Biggl)=
$$
but unfortunately I did not able to do this. However by the mean value theorem **(is this true?)** I know that there must exist $\theta_t\in(0,1)$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0+\theta_t(t-t_0))=\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\int_S\Biggl(\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}\Biggl)=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\int_S\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0+\theta_t(t-t_0))
$$
and so I think that the resul follows showing that if $t\rightarrow t_0$ then $\theta_t\rightarrow 0$ but unfortunately I did not able to do this. Finally by the mean value integral theorem we know that for each $t\in I$ exists $\xi_t\in S$ such that
$$
\int_S\Biggl(\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}\Biggl)=\frac{f(\xi,t)-f(\xi,t_0)}{t-t_0}\cdot\text{vol}(S)
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\int_S\Biggl(\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}\Biggl)=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\Biggl(\frac{f(\xi,t)-f(\xi,t_0)}{t-t_0}\cdot\text{vol}(S)\Biggl)=\\
\Biggl(\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{f(\xi,t)-f(\xi,t_0)}{t-t_0}\Biggl)\cdot\text{vol}(S)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\xi,t_0)\cdot\text{vol}(S)
$$
so that the statement follows showing that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\xi,t_0)\cdot\text{vol}(S)=\int_S\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)
$$
but again I did not able to do this. So could someone help me, please? **I point out I did NOT study Lebesgue integration theory so I courteously ask to do not use it, thanks.**

Comment: I think [Section A.5 of Durrett's text](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf#page=478) may be relevant. It gives conditions under which the desired equality holds.

Comment: @angryavian It seems really needless to point out I did **NOT** study Lebesgue integration theory...

Comment: If you look at the proof, it seems to only rely on Fubini's theorem, which you can [prove for Riemann integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Riemann_integrals).

Comment: @angryavian Sorry, I saw the final section $A.5$ but I did not find the thorem. So I will read it if you says to me the page of your linked pdf where I can find the proof.

Comment: Theorem A.5.1, page 470-471 printed (478-479 of the PDF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, we have

$$\frac{f(x,t) - f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,\xi)$$ where $\xi$ is between $t$ and $t_0$ and may depend on $x$.

The easiest proof arises with the strongest hypothesis where $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S \times I$.  In that case we have

$$\left|\int_S \frac{f(x,t)- f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0} -\int_S \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)\right| \leqslant \int_S \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,\xi)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0) \right|, $$

By uniform continuity, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ depending only on $\epsilon$, such that if $|x_1 - x_2| < \delta $ and $ |t_1 - t_2| < \delta$, then

$$\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x_1,t_1)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x_2,t_2) \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{vol(S)}$$

Hence, if $|t-t_0| < \delta$ it follows that $|\xi - t_0| < \delta$ and

$$\left|\int_S \frac{f(x,t)- f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0} -\int_S \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)\right| < \epsilon$$

Whence,

$$\left.\frac{d}{dt} \int_s f(x,t)\right|_{t = t_0} = \int_S \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (x, t_0)$$

Answer (score 0):

So we know that if $S$ is integrable (i.e. it is rectifiable) then $\text{cl} S$ is integrable too: now if $S$ is bounded the set $\text{cl}S$ is compact so that the set $\operatorname{cl}S\times[t_0,t]$ is rectifiable being a simple region and thus if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is there continuous then it is there integrable too. So we observe that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{x\in S}f(x,t):=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{\int_{x\in S} f(x,t)-\int_{x\in S}f(x,t_0)}{t-t_0}=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{\int_{x\in S}\big(f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)\big)}{t-t_0}=\\\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{1}{t-t_0}\int_{x\in\text{cl}S}\big(f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)\big) =\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{1}{t-t_0}\int_{x\in\text{cl}S}\int_{t_0}^t\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) =\\\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\frac{1}{t-t_0}\int_{t_0}^t\int_{x\in\text{cl}S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)=\int_{x\in\text{cl}S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)=\int_{\text{bd}S\,\cup\,\text{int}S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)=\\\int_{\text{bd}S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)+\int_{\text{int}S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)-\int_{\text{bd}S\,\cap\,\text{int}S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)=\int_{\text{int}S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)=\int_{x\in S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)$$
so that the result follows immediately.

Comment: Looks OK. You could also use the mean value theorem.  Basically it is straighforward as you have a very smooth $C^1$ function.

Comment: @RRL Okay. So how use the mean value theorem? As you can see in the question I tried to use it without success. So could you show it to me, please? I am really curious about.

Comment: Are we given that $f$ is continuous on $S\times I$ or just that $f$ is $C^1$ with respect o

Comment: ... $C^1$ in the second argument

Comment: Also, is $S$ compact?

Comment: @RRL I do not precisely know if S must be compact: I discovered the identity in a Fluidynamic text but there it is not proved so that I posted a question. Anyway if my proof is correct surely S must not be compact generally, right?

Comment: Surely the more important problem of my answer is to justify the use of Fundamental theorem of Calculus, because it is necessary that the function $$F(t):=\int_{x\in\text{cl}S}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)$$ is continuous to apply it, right?

Comment: So how prove that the above function if continuous?

Comment: I gave you an easy proof under strong conditions.  You could try to relax the conditions and see where that leads you.

Comment: @RRL Oh yeah, I saw! So thanks very much for your assistance: you was really courteous with me, thanks yet.