# İf $\lim x_{n}=x$ then how to show this equation?

Tags: calculus

If  $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n}=x$ equality is true how to show this equations? $\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac {x_{1}+x_{2}+\ldots +x_{n}} {n}=x$

Comment: What does n go to on the limits? $\pm\infty$? $0$?

Comment: @TehRod $+\infty$

Comment: @furkans then put that in the question as well as what you have tried

Comment: @furkans Edit your question to show that - `$\lim_n\rightarrow-\infty...$` is the mathjax

Comment: This is called Cesàro Mean.

Comment: this is called the Cesaro Mean of a sequence a proof on M.SE can be shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565288/can-you-please-check-my-cesaro-means-proof).

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/514802/9464

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$

We have that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n=x$ thus $\exists n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-x|< \epsilon, \forall n \geqslant n_1$

$|\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}-x|=|\frac{(x_1-x)+...(x_{n_1-1}-x)}{n}+\frac{(x_{n_1}-x)+...+(x_n-x)}{n}| \leqslant \frac{|x_1-x|+...+|x_{n_1-1}-x|}{n}+ \frac{|x_{n_1-1}-x|+...+|x_n-x|}{n}$

Exists $n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\frac{|x_1-x|+...+|x_{n_1-1}-x|}{n}< \epsilon, \forall n \geqslant n_2$$

Now for $n \geqslant n_0= \max\{n_1,n_2\}$

$|\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}-x| \leqslant \epsilon+ \frac{(n-n_1) }{n}\epsilon<2 \epsilon $