# how can I show this equations? $\lim \left( x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}\right) ^{\frac {1} {n}}=x_{0}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $x_{n}>0$ for all $n\in {\bf N}$ and $\lim_n x_{n}=x_{0}>0$. How can I show that 
$$
\lim_n \left( x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}\right)^{\frac {1} {n}}=x_{0}\quad ?
$$

Comment: Instead of commas, shouldn't it be a product?

Comment: Take the logarithm and then use your previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2352889/9464

Comment: @Jack i tried but I did not show the right side of the equation

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$
\log \left( ( x_1 x_2 ... x_n)^{1/n} \right) = \frac{1}{n} \log(x_1 x_2 ... x_n) = \frac{1}{n} ( \log(x_1) + \log(x_2) + ... + \log(x_n) ) = \frac{\log(x_1) + \log(x_2) + ... + \log(x_n)}{n}
$$

As $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \log(x_n) = \log( \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty } x_n ) = \log(x_0) $, we deduce that 
$$ 
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{\log(x_1) + \log(x_2) + ... + \log(x_n)}{n} =
 \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty } \log(x_n) = \log(x_0)
$$
And finally
$$
\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty } \log \left( ( x_1 x_2 ... x_n)^{1/n} \right) =\log \left( \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty } ( x_1 x_2 ... x_n)^{1/n} \right) = \log(x_0) \longrightarrow \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty } ( x_1 x_2 ... x_n)^{1/n} = x_0
$$

Comment: You should show how you deduced that $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\log(x_1) + \log(x_2) + ... + \log(x_n)}{n} = \lim_{ n \to \infty } \log(x_n) = \log(x_0)$$While it is true, the readers who are unfamiliar with, for example, the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem, might not understand why it is true.

Comment: But the user who asked this has this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2352889/9464

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)$ be defined by

$$f(n)=\left(\prod_{m=1}^n x_m\right)^{1/n}$$

Clearly the logarithm of $f(n)$ is given by

$$\log(f(n))=\frac1n \sum_{m=1}^n\log(x_m)$$

From the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\log(f(n)) &=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac1n \sum_{m=1}^n\log(x_m)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \frac{\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}\log(x_m)-\sum_{m=1}^{n}\log(x_m)}{(n+1)-n}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\log(x_{n+1})\\\\
&=\log(x_0)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can