# It is true that if $\lim _n a_n = 0$, then $\lim_n\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^n|a_j|=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

It is true that if $\lim _n a_n = 0$, then $\lim_n\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^n|a_j|=0$ ?

Comment: Next time please provide what you have tried so far

Comment: @DavidMitra The question is if the limit is zero, then the Cesaro Mean converges to the same limit. In case zero

Comment: See the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514802/convergence-of-series-implies-convergence-of-cesaro-mean).

Comment: Thank you for your help @DavidMitra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and I would do this by splitting the sum. Let $\epsilon>0$ and take $N$ large so that $m>N$ implies $|a_m|<\epsilon.$ Then for $n>N$ we have

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^n|a_j|=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}|a_j|}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=N}^n|a_j|\leq\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}|a_j|}{n}+\frac{1}{n}(n\epsilon)=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}|a_j|}{n}+\epsilon.$$
By order limits 
$$0\leq\lim_{n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^n|a_j|\leq\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitary we have 
$$\lim_{n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^n|a_j|=0$$
as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: This is an answer to the previous post which has been edited.

False:

Take $a_n=\frac{1}{\log{n}}$

Comment: The statement has been edited. This is an answer to the former post

Comment: OK, I hadn't noticed that. – Perhaps you should add that information to the answer, as it is currently misleading.