# Convergence of a double Cesaro mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, cesaro-summable

Am asked to show that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \rho^{|i-j|}\to \frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho} \quad \text{as} \quad n\to\infty$$
where $\rho$ is a number satisfying $|\rho|<1$.

My attempt:

Think of an $n\times n$ matrix having coefficient $\rho^{|i-j|}$ in position $(i,j)$. The coefficients are constant along the diagonals $|i-j|=k$ for $k=0,\dots, n-1$. Summing across these  diagonals we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \rho^{|i-j|}=2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i)\rho^i -n$$ and so
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \rho^{|i-j|}=2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \rho^i-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i\rho^i -1$$
The first term on the RHS converges to $\frac{2}{1-\rho}$. For the second term we use l'Hospital's rule to get

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} x\rho^x=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{e^{-x\log(\rho)}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{-1}{\log(\rho)e^{-x\log(\rho^)}}=0$$

and so the using the result from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/514811/522332) we get that the second term converges to zero. The conclusion follows.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right. The sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i \rho^i$ can also be computed using the derivative of $\rho \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \rho^i$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan How? If $f(\rho)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \rho^i$ then $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i \rho^i=\rho f'(\rho)$. Can it be more explicit?

Comment: Of course, because $f(\rho) = (1-\rho^n)/(1-\rho)$ whenever $\rho \ne 1$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Ah yes I get $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i \rho^i=\frac{1-\rho^n}{(1-\rho)^2}-\frac{n\rho^{n-1}}{1-\rho} \to \frac{1}{(1-\rho)^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach.  Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \rho^{|i-j|}&=1+\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\rho^{i-j}\\\\
&=1+\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^n \rho^i \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\left(\frac1{\rho}\right)^j\\\\
&=1+\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\rho-\rho^i}{1-\rho}\\\\
&=\frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho}-\frac2{n(1-\rho)} \sum_{i=1}^n \rho^{i} 
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \rho^{|i-j|}&=\frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I prefer this approach!

Comment: @alphie Pleased to hear. I upvoted your question.  (+1)