# How can I show that $b_n \rightarrow a$?

Tags: analysis

Knowing that $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$. How can I show that $b_n \rightarrow a$?

Comment: Do you want an exact or intuitive proof?

Comment: @Ragnar I want an exact proof.

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means) the first duplicate I found.

Answer (score 1):

Easily $$\sup_{1\le i\le n}a_i \ge b_n = \dfrac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}{n}\ge\inf_{1\le i\le n}a_i$$ As $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a\implies\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$.

Thus by Sandwich theorem we have our desired result.