# Convergence of $na_{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am given an increasing sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that $0< a_n\le 1,\ n\ge 1$. Can we say that the sequence $$b_n:=na_{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k,\quad n\ge 1$$ converges? And if we can then are there conditions on $a_n$ for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer that gives an upper bound on $b_n$, together with a counterexample to convergence in general. Since $$\frac{b_n}{n} = a_{n + 1} - \frac 1 n \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k$$

it follows that $b_n/n$ gives the difference between $a_{n + 1}$ and the average of the first $n$ terms of the sequence. Since $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence, this limit converges to $0$; see, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means). This gives a bound on the growth of $b_n$.

However, it's not true that $\{b_n\}$ must converge; consider a slowly increasing sequence, such as

$$a_k = 1 - \frac 1 k$$

Then $$\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k =n - H_n$$

with $H_n$ being the $n$th harmonic number. In this case, we have

$$n a_{n + 1} - \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k = n - \frac{n}{n + 1} - (n - H_n) = H_n - \frac{n}{n + 1}$$

which diverges to infinity. Note that it has logarithmic growth, in accordance with the bound above.

---

In some sense, the averages lag behind the current term, due to the slow convergence of the sequence (or the slow divergence of the partial sums $\sum (1 - a_n)$; faster convergence can guarantee that the limit exists. For example, if we choose $a_n = 1-\frac{1}{2^n}$, the corresponding sequence $\{b_n\}$ does converge.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\{ a_{n} \}$ is monotone increasing and bounded, it converges to a limit $\alpha$. Then it is easy to check that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\alpha - a_{n}). $$

(Of course, we are not excluding the possibility that this diverges to $\infty$.) Since $c_{n} = \alpha - a_{n}$ can be any decreasing sequence having values in $[0, \alpha]$, there seems no easy criterion for the convergence of $\{ b_{n} \}$.

Answer (score 2):

Answer above confirms that $(b_n)$ can be both convergent or divergent. As for a precise characterisation of convergence of $(b_n)$ in terms on $(a_n)$ it might be useful to look at rates of Cauchy convergence, since the relationship between the two sequences is seen most clearly in terms of differences i.e. $$(b_{n+1}-b_n)=(n+1)(a_{n+1}-a_n).$$ It could be that one could prove something like "$(b_n)$ converges iff $(a_n)$ has rate of Cauchy convergence $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$" for some reasonably simple function $f(n)$.

Sorry if that sounds a bit cryptic: I haven't the energy right now to think any harder! Maybe it's much easier than that.