# Show that for a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_n$ $\lim_n a_n=0$ implies $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, cesaro-summable

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be q sequence of real numbers with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Show that this implies
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert=0.
$$

This is my idea how to prove it, unfortunately do not know if it is right:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, then there exists a $N(\varepsilon)$ with $\lvert a_n\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $n\geqslant N(\varepsilon)$.

So it is 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lvert a_i\rvert=\sum_{i=0}^{N(\varepsilon)-1}\lvert a_i\rvert+\sum_{i=N(\varepsilon)}^{\infty}\lvert a_i\rvert\leqslant\sum_{i=0}^{N(\varepsilon)-1}\lvert a_i\rvert+\sum_{i=N(\varepsilon)}^{\infty}\varepsilon\leqslant M
$$
for a $M\geqslant 0$ for $\varepsilon \to 0$.

So the limits exists. Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, i.e. the limit exsits, too, one can write the limit as the product of both limits, i.e.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert=0\cdot M=0.
$$

Comment: It is not true that if $a_n\rightarrow 0$ then $\sum |a_n|$ converges or that $\sum |a_n|\rightarrow M$. Try $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Ok, I think one counterexample is a_n:=1/n. Can you tell me then how to prove it?

Comment: Try to bound the partial sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum |a_n|$.

Comment: For example $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert\leqslant n\cdot\max_{0\leq i\leq n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert$$

Comment: Read [stolz-cesaro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) and [proof](http://planetmath.org/proofofstolzcesarotheorem).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean

Comment: You could have a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means) and perhaps other [questions linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/207910) for a slightly more general result.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is as follows:

Ignore $a_0$. As $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, for each $ε_n = 1/n^2$, we can find an integer $N(n)$ such that $|a_n| < 1/n^2$ for every $n \ge N(n)$.
Then: $$sum_{k=1}^n |a_k| < sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^2 < sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^2 =\pi^2/6 $$ Then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1/n)\times(sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|) \le \lim_{n\to\infty} 1/n\times\pi^2/6 = 0$$

Comment: But why $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lvert a_k\rvert < \sum_{k=1}^{n}1/k^2$?

Comment: From the assumption of $a_n$, I can choose $ε$ to be any arbitrarily small positive number (in this case is $1/n^2$). UNDER THAT CHOICE, I have $|a_n| < 1/n^2$, and thus same for the sum you asked.

Comment: But only for $n\geqslant N(n)$.

Comment: The limit basically tells you that starting from some index ($N(n)$), the sequence will be very close to its limit (0), so it doesn't matter how the sequence behaves before that.

Comment: I nvertheless think its not right, because in the second sum it shouldn't be 1/k^2 but 1/n^2 because thats the fixed epsilon and not 1/k^2 with index k in the sum.,

Comment: I've edited a bit on $ε$, it should be understood as depending on $n$. About $k$, it is just purely notation to indicate that you taking the sum from 1 to n.

Comment: I really cannot understand you, I am sorry for that. I simply do not understand why $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lvert a_k\rvert < \sum_{k=1}^{n}1/k^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Is very easy with [Cesàro-Stolz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert a_i\rvert}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=|\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n|=0.$$

Comment: We never had that theorem, so I do not think that I shall use that.

Comment: But you can see the proof and use it in this particular case.