# Does the fact that the sum is bounded imply every element is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n,m} \geq 0$ for all $n,m$. Suppose there exists an $M$, such that for any $T$, $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n,m=1}^Ta_{n,m}\leq M$. Can we find another constant $C$, such that $a_{n,m}\leq C\ \forall n,m$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1105424/42969 for a one-dimensional counterexample, which can easily be extended to a two-dimensional counterexample.

Comment: Consider the sequence M,0,2M,0,0,3M,0,0,0,4M,0,0,0,0,5M,....

Comment: Ah sorry, did not notice that $T$ is not fixed.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis What if we require $a_{n,m} >0$ for all $n,m$

Comment: You can make everything non-zero by adding for example $2^{-(n+m)}$ to each $a_{n,m}$ which has a finite sum.

Comment: @MartinR Hi, sorry I see one-dimensional case works, but I cannot easily figure out the two-dimensional counterexample from this since it is divided by T not $T^2$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis the original sequence does not have bound sum divided by T.

Comment: Just put the one-dimensional sequence from my first comment along the diagonal $a_{n,n}$, and let all non-diagonal entries be $0$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis   Ah I see Thanks.