# If a sequence of points approaches a convex compact set, then the limit of Cesàro means is in the set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^d$ such that $x_n \to A$ where $A$ is convex  compact. If 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k \to x$$

then is it true that $x \in A$.

I am not able to prove it nor getting counter example.

Comment: What's a realtion?

Comment: It is not always clear to an unsuspecting person whether $x_n$ refers to an individual element of a sequence or the entire sequence. Context helps. Sometimes one can suspect an unfamiliar context and walk away, but this is not always clear. Notation is often overloaded in math, so if you see that a fellow user misunderstood, surely there's no harm explaining what the notation means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(y)=\operatorname{dist}(y,A)$. Observe that $f$ is a nonnegative continuous convex function and its zero set is precisely $A$.

By assumption, $f(x_n)\to 0$. It is  a [standard fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207910/147263) that the means of the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converge to $0$. Since
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k \right)\le 
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k) \to 0
$$
it follows that $f(x)=0$, as desired.

---

Note that compactness is not needed: being closed and convex is enough.