# If $\lim_{n \to\infty}a_n=a$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}=a$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, limits

If $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}=a$
I need to prove this, and was thinking to use some inequality related to the geometric and harmonic, but unfortunately my efforts did not pan out as hoped. Does anyone know how this would be proven?

Comment: Cesaro sum $\ddot\smile$

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means