# $ \lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1a_2...a_n)^{1/n} = a $ (check the logic)

Tags: limits, proof-verification

$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1a_2...a_n)^{1/n} = a$ and we know that $ \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$

**My proof:** $| (a_1a_2...a_n)^{1/n} - a| <| (a_na_n...a_n)^{1/n} - a| = | (a_n)^{n/n} - a| = | a_n - a| < \epsilon $

My question is: is this proof correct? If no, where did I do a mistake?

Comment: No.  Where does your first inequality come from?  Are you assuming the $a_n$ sequence is monotonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that you are calculating the n-root I would assume that $a_n>0$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a \iff \lim_{n\to \infty} \ln{a_n} = \ln{a}$$

Then:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1a_2...a_n)^{1/n}=\exp{\ln{\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1a_2...a_n)^{1/n}}}=\exp{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln{a_i}}$$

Using  [Cesaro Means](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means):

$$\exp{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln{a_i}}=\exp{\ln{a}}=a$$