# If $a_k\geq0$ is a decreasing sequence converging to $0$, do we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}n = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_k\geq 0$ be a non-increasing sequence satisfying $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0$. Is it always true that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}n=0$$
?

I tried proving with "brute force" but failed: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists a $K\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_k\le\varepsilon$ for all $k\geq K$. Let $C=\sum_{k=1}^K a_k$. We have $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac C\varepsilon\right\rceil}a_k}{\left\lceil\frac C\varepsilon\right\rceil}=\frac{C}{\left\lceil\frac C\varepsilon\right\rceil}+\sum_{k=K+1}^{\left\lceil\frac C\varepsilon\right\rceil} a_k\le \varepsilon +\varepsilon\cdot\left( \left\lceil\frac C\varepsilon\right\rceil-K\right).$$

However, this is not good, as the right-hand side depends on $C$, which can get large for small $\varepsilon$.

Also, numerical computations for example with $a_k=\frac1{\log\log k}$ seem to confirm the statement though...

(Additionally, note that I didn't use the non-increasing fact, but I am not sure if it is needed.)

Comment: I don't think you need the decreasing fact, because this is true more generally; if $(a_k)$ converges to $\alpha$ then $\lim ((1/n) \sum a_k) = \alpha$.

Comment: You forgot to divide the sum in the middle term by $\lceil C/\varepsilon \rceil$.

Comment: Yes, according to [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: Technically, the answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669790/lim-n-rightarrow-infty-x-n1-x-n-c-c-0-then-is-x-n-n-c).

Comment: @Savio Your comment best answers my question I think

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. But you don't need to take $n = \lceil\frac{C}{\epsilon}\rceil$. Simply take $n>K+1$. Then you have:$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{n} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^K a_k}{n} + \frac{\sum_{k=K+1}^n a_k}n \le \frac{\sum_{k=1}^K a_1}{n} + \frac{\sum_{k=K+1}^n \epsilon}n \le \frac{K a_1}{n} + \frac{(n-K)\epsilon}n
$$
As $n$ goes to infinity, the RHS approaches $\epsilon$. In particular, for $n>N$ (with appropriate choice of $N$), the whole thing is bounded by $2\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Continue from "Then there is a $K\gt 0$ such that $a_i\lt\epsilon$ for all $i\gt K$.

(Say the sequence started from $a_0$)
Then let $N$ be an integer larger than $\max\{\frac {a_0} {\epsilon} K,K\}$. Since $a_i$ is non increasing, $\sum _{i=0} ^K a_i \le Ka_0$, and $\sum _{i=K} ^N a_i\le (N-K)\epsilon$. Then for all $n\gt N$, $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}n\lt\epsilon$.