# Let $\{x_n\}$ be sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}({x_{n+1}}-{x_n})=5$. Then find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n \log n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I am unable to solve this problem. I tried using the definition of the limit of sequences. I took an example by considering a sequence $x_n= 5n$. Then I got that, the limit was zero.

$x_{n+1}-x_n=(5n+5)-5n=5$.
Then,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n \log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n}{n \log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5}{\log n}=0$$.

But I am unable to solve it in general. Please help me. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hint. There is $N$ s.t if $n\ge N$, $0<4<x_{n+1}-x_n<6$.

Comment: And also some $N$ such that $x_{n+1} - x_n > 4$ for $n \ge N$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx_n%7D%7Bn%5Clog%20n%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D(%7Bx_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D-%7Bx_n%7D)%3D5%24&p=1), there's the fairly similar [prove that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$ exist then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$](/q/2573633), with the question it's closed to as a duplicate, & the one which the other one is closed as a duplicate, have many other related linked questions.

Comment: Indeed, using https://math.stackexchange.com/q/669790/42969 we get $x_n/n \to 5$, which implies $x_n/ (n \log n) \to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply the [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_*/%E2%88%9E_case), as $n\log(n)$ is strictly monotone and approaches $+\infty$, and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{(n+1)\log(n+1)-n\log(n)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{n\log(\frac{n+1}{n})+\log(n+1)}=0$$

because $x_{n+1}-x_n$ converges hence bounded while $n\log(\frac{n+1}{n})+\log(n+1)\ge n$ approaches $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there is an $N$ such that for $n \ge N$, $4 < x_{n+1} - x_n < 6$. Then, for all $n\ge N$,

$$x_N + 4(n-N) < x_n = x_N + \sum_{k=N}^{n-1} x_{k+1} - x_k < x_N + 6(n-N)$$

And now we divide by $n \log n$ and use the Sandwich theorem, so the sought limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Every convergent sequence is bounded. Thus $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le C$ for some $C> 0$ and every $n.$ WLOG we may assume that $C\ge |x_1|.$ By the triangle inequality  $$|x_n|\le \sum_{k=2}^n|x_k-x_{k-1}|+|x_1|\le Cn$$ and the conclusion follows.