# A problem of limit: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left\{\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!} \right\}^{(1/n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to find the limit of $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left\{\left(\frac{2}1\right) \left(\frac{3}2\right)^{2} \left(\frac{4}3\right)^{3} ... \left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n} \right\}^{(1/n)}$$

Cancelling out the same quantities in numerators and denominators, I have reached the step: $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left\{\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!} \right\}^{\frac1n}$$

Now I am stuck here. I have searched google for help, but found only the result for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{n!} \right\}^{(\frac1n)}$.

Which formulae/properties should I use now to proceed from this stage?

Edit: The options for the answer are: a) $e$, b) $1/e$, c) $\pi$, d) $1/\pi$

Comment: Now you can use the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475786/how-to-compute-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n-left-2n12n2-cdots2nn and   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq

Comment: Looking at your edit and the options, I bet that the limit is for $n \to \infty$ and not for $n\to 0$. One more typo in a textbook ?

Comment: Perhaps it is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Taking logarithm on both the sides,
we get $$\log(y_n)=\log((\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!})^{\frac{1}{n}})$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\{\log\frac{2}{1}+2\log\frac{3}{2}+...+n\log\frac{n+1}{n}\}.$$
Using [Cauchy's First theorem on limits](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111105069/17)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\{\log\frac{2}{1}+2\log\frac{3}{2}+...+n\log\frac{n+1}{n}\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\frac{n+1}{n}=1$$

Comment: Am I correct? do you find anything wrong in these steps?please tell me.

Comment: The question states $\lim\limits_{n\to0}$, you used infinity.

Comment: @Kawrno: $n\to 0$ does not make sense here as $n$ is clearly a positive integer. The right answer is $e$ as given here.

Comment: [Another source for the theorem used can be found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533626/convergence-of-the-arithmetic-mean)

Comment: Thank you very much@B.Mehta

Answer (score 1):

As you say, $n \to 0$ is rather unusual. So, let us consider the case of $x \to 0$ for

$$A=\left(\frac{(x+1)^x}{x!}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{x+1}{ \Gamma (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}}\implies \log(A)=\log(x+1)-\frac 1x\log (\Gamma (x+1))$$ Now, close to $x=0$ (have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7)),
$$\log (\Gamma (x+1))=-\gamma  x+\frac{\pi ^2 x^2}{12}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\frac 1x\log (\Gamma (x+1))=-\gamma  +\frac{\pi ^2 x}{12}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ making $$\log(A)=\gamma +\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}\right) x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=e^\gamma \left(1+\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}\right) x+O\left(x^2\right) \right)$$

For illustration purposes, let $x=10^{-k}$ and compare the values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation}& \text{exact} \\
 0 & 2.097271488 & 2.000000000 \\
 1 & 1.812692325 & 1.811281476 \\
 2 & 1.784234409 & 1.784219608 \\
 3 & 1.781388617 & 1.781388468 \\
 4 & 1.781104038 & 1.781104036 \\
 5 & 1.781075580 & 1.781075580
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the $\log$ and you find $$\log(n+1) - \log(n) + \log(n) - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k) = \log(1+\frac{1}{n}) - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log(\frac{k}{n}) \rightarrow -\int_0^1 \log(x) \mathrm d x = 1$$

as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: How to transform $\lim\limits_{n\to{\infty}}$ to $\lim\limits_{n\to0}$ ?

Comment: @Kawrno $n\rightarrow 0$ does not make sense if $n$ is integer.

Comment: I wrote as the question was written.

Answer (score -1):

Well, $e$ is the limit of $\left(\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Indeed:

By Stirling's Approximation, $n!$ is $(1+o(1)\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$. So $\left(\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}$ is

$[\sqrt{2\pi n}]^{1/n} \left(\left(\frac{n}{e(n+1)}\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$ which is $e^{-1}$.

Was that the question that was meant to be asked?