# Prove that if $x_n$ converges to $\omega$, $t_n$ converges to $\omega$ too

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

By the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$, define a new sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ such that $t_n:=\frac {x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}$. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n=\omega$, how can I show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\omega$?

Original post had ``If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\omega$, ..."

Comment: This is a standard question and has been asked a number of times on this site. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533626/convergence-of-the-arithmetic-mean), for instance.

Comment: @Randall hah you linked the same thing that JWP_HTX did

Comment: @CameronWilliams it is an auto comment from my VTC

Comment: @Randall Oh yep I see. I didn't realize it would let you mark something as two different kinds of duplicates!