# Showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {s_n} n \to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\sum a_k$ be an infinite series and $s_n$ be the partial sums. we can assume that $\lim_{k \to \infty}ka_k = 0$.  I want to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {s_n} n = 0$$

and am not sure how to do it. I thought about multiplying both top and bottom by $n$ so that we might use the assumption $\lim_{k \to \infty}ka_k = 0$ but this only eliminates some tail terms.

Comment: Have you heard about Cesaro's lemma ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe No I haven't although now just looking it up I can see it might apply here. But is there another way to do it without it?

Comment: @AdamRubinson sorry, a typo, thikn I confused myself with another problem

Comment: Also, I'm fairly certain I have seen this question many times before on this site.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I tried searching but the results were almost all probability related

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} k*a_k=0$ then ofcourse $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} a_k=0$. But then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac {S_n} n=0$ by [convergence of arithmetic mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533626/convergence-of-the-arithmetic-mean).