# Find a limit related to a convergent series.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series and $S=\lim{s_n}$ where $s_n$ is the $n$th partial sum, how would I prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{s_1+...+s_n}{n} = S$?

I'm not sure where to start, I've been having trouble understanding partial sums. Any tips on where to begin?

Comment: answered this a day or two ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103817/if-sum-a-n-is-a-convergent-series-with-s-lim-s-n-where-s-n-is-the-nth/2103833#2103833

Answer (score 0):

See my answer (or other answers) at [If $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series with $S = \lim s_n$, where $s_n$ is the nth partial sum, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_1+...+s_n}{n} = S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103817/if-sum-a-n-is-a-convergent-series-with-s-lim-s-n-where-s-n-is-the-nth/2103833#2103833)

In reference to your question about understanding partial sums, the partial sum for the series $\sum a_k$ is defined as $$ s_n = \sum_{k=1}^na_k.$$

So $$s_1 = a_1\\s_2=a_1+a_2\\s_3 = a_1+a_2+a_3$$

etc. So the partial sum for the series is what you'd get if you added it up and stopped at $n.$

We take $n\rightarrow \infty$ in the formula above and write $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots$$ so the sum of the infinite series is defined by the limit of the sequence of partial sums, if the limit exists.

The limit in your problem is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{s_1+s_2+\ldots s_n}{n}$$ which you can think of as the "long run average" of the sequence of partial sums. So you are asked to show that if the sequence $s_n\rightarrow S$ then the long-run average is equal to $S.$ (This is actually true for any convergent sequence... the fact that this sequence comes from the partial sum of a series is immaterial.)

A key fact is that sometimes the "long-run average" of a sequence exists even when the sequence does not converge (can you think of an example?). This is the origin of the definition of [Cesaro summability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation). What you're proving here is that if a series converges, its Cesaro sum exists and has the same value.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has two parts: 1. The definition of a convergent infinite series; 2. Basic theorem of Cesaro: If $x_n \to L,$ then $(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)/n \to L.$

Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n= S.$ By definition, this means $S_n \to S,$ where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k.$ By Cesaro, this implies $(S_1 + \cdots + S_n)/n \to S.$

So I haven't proved Cesaro, which has been proved on MSE approximately $734$ times. But I thought it was worthwhile pointing out that the series result here, after you see through the incense and incantations, is just Cesaro's basic result on sequences.