# If $a_n>0$ converges to $a>0$, then $(a_0 a_1\cdots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to $a.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I would appreciate your help!

How can we show that if a sequence of positive real numbers $a_n$ converges to $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$, then $(a_0 a_1\cdots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to $a$ as well.

Comment: We want the $a_i$ to be $\gt 0$. Without that, the result can fail in various ways.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you realize that, as André Nicolas points out, the result is false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following facts

1. If a sequence of positive terms converges to a positive limit, then its Arithmetic Mean also converges to the same limit (for a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248116/arithmetic-mean-of-a-sequence-converges)).
2. If **A.M.** (Arithmetic Mean) of a positive sequence converges, then the **G.M.** (Geometric Mean) of that sequence also converges to the same limit (this can be obtained by observing the fact that  **A.M.**  $\ge$ **G.M.**$\ge$ **H.M.**).
3. If $M>0$ then the sequence $M^\frac{1}{n}\to 1$

one can obtain the required result.

For **details** see below.

> **Step-1:** So if $a_n>0$ and $a_n\to a$ for some $a>0$, then $a_n$ is a bounded sequence i.e. $\exists\, M>0$ such that $a_n\le M$ for all $n\ge 0$. Let $A_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n{a_k}$, $G_n=\left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^n{a_k}\right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ and $H_n=\dfrac{n+1}{\frac{1}{a_0}+\dotsm+\frac{1}{a_n}}$. Then [clearly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248116/arithmetic-mean-of-a-sequence-converges) $A_n\to a$. Also using the same argument, applying to the sequence $\frac{1}{a_n}$ one can obtain $H_n\to a$. Since $H_n\le G_n\le A_n$ for all $n\ge 0$, we have $|H_n-a|\le |G_n-a|\le |A_n-a|$, for all $n\ge 0$. Hence by the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), we have $G_n\to a$.
>
> **Step-2:** Now let $b_n=\left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^n{a_k}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$. We now prove that $b_n\to a$. Choose $\varepsilon>0$. As $G_n$ is convergent, there is a $M^\prime>0$ such that $G_n\le M^\prime$ for all $n\ge 0$ and also there is a $n_1\in\Bbb N$ such that $|G_n-a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\ge n_1$. Since $M^\frac{1}{n}\to 1$,  there is a $n_2\in \Bbb N$ such that $\left|M^\frac{1}{n}-1\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M^\prime}$ for all $n\ge n_2$. Choose $n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$. So if $n\ge n_0$, we have
>
> \begin{eqnarray}
> |b_n-a| & \le & |G_n-a|+|b_n-G_n|\\
> &<& \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+ G_n\left|\left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^n{a_k}\right)^\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-1\right|\\
> &\le& \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+M^\prime\left|M^\frac{1}{n}-1\right|\quad\quad(\text{since}\,\, a_n\le M)\\
> &<& \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.
> \end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 5):

Look at $\exp (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^n \log a_m)$ and since $\log a_m\rightarrow \log a$ (assuming $a_n,a\neq 0$), you can apply the [Cesaro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean).

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $a \neq 0$. Suppose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq N$, $|a_n| > \epsilon$.

Then for  $n \geq N$ know that:

$\log(a_n) \to \log(a) \implies \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \log(a_n)=\log(a) \iff (a_Na_{N+1}...a_{N+k})^{\frac{1}{k}} \to a$.

You should be able to figure out the rest. (Note you will need that $a_n \neq 0 \forall n$. In fact, assuming this, you can show that you can take $N=0$ in the above.).