# does the sequence ${a_n}$ converges implies it is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

does the sequence ${a_n}$ converges implies it is bounded?
i think the answer is no, but i've seen a proof used this fact and our TA used this fact in class as the following question:
[arithmetic mean of a sequence converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248116/arithmetic-mean-of-a-sequence-converges)

Comment: What is the sequence in? Is it a sequence of reals? Extended reals?

Comment: The only information given about this sequence is $lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$, thank you!

Comment: It is true, unless one makes insane conventional choices, like letting the sequence be in the extended reals, $[-\infty,\infty]$, setting $a_1=\infty$, and $a_n=1$ for $n>1$. But then we need to still use the ridiculous convention that infinite quantities in the extended reals are unbounded.

Comment: If $L$ is real the answer is yes, if $L$ is extended real the answer is no. Even if $a_n$ real when $L$ is allowed to be extended real the answer is no as the example $a_n=n$ shows.

Comment: @dioid: I don't think it makes much sense to interpret this question in the extended reals, because that is not a metric space at all (though it is metrizable), and therefore speaking of "bounded" is not even meaningful.

Comment: @Henning Makholm I would agree to that. I just wasn't able to find the justification you just provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

Suppose the sequence converves to some $L\in\mathbb R$. Then *by definition of convergence*, there is an $N$ such that all terms in the squence after $a_n$ are within a distance of $1$ from $L$.

If *all* terms have a distance to $L$ of at most $1$, then we're done, of course. *Otherwise*, there are at most $N$ elements of the sequence whose distance to $L$ is *more than* $1$. That is finitely many, so one of them will be *farthest from* $L$. Let the distance from that term to $L$ be $a$.

Now every term in the sequence is within the open ball $B_{a+1}(L)$. Thus, it is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be YES. (I assume that your setting is in the real number)

Now Assume it converges to a finite number a, then for large N, $a_n$ would be close enough to your limit a for all $n>N$ which means they are uniformly bounded by some number which we shall call it $M$. Finally, pick the maximum of the first N terms $a_1.....a_N$ and this uniform bound $M$, this maximum will be your upper bound for the whole sequence.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n$ converges means that
there is a limit $L$
such that,
for any $\epsilon > 0$,
there is an $N(\epsilon)$
such that
$|a_n-L|
< \epsilon$
for $n > N(\epsilon)$.

Set $\epsilon = 1$.

Then
$|a_n - L| < 1$
for $n > N(1)$.

Therefore
$L-1 < a_n < L+1$
for $n > N(1)$,
so that the $a_n$
are bounded for $n > N(1)$
by $|L|+1$.

Since there are only a finite number of
$n \le N(1)$,
there is a bound on those $a_n$
of $\max_{n=1}^{N(1)} |a_n|$.

Therefore all the $a_n$ are bounded
by
$\max(|L|+1, \max_{n=1}^{N(1)} |a_n|)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *yes*. Since $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is convergent by assumption, let $a$ its limit. Then for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for every $n>m$. In particular there exist $\bar{m}$ such that $|a_n|<1+|a|$ for every $n>\bar{m}$.

Now the set $\{a_1,\cdots a_\bar{m}\}$ is finite, and let $M$ the maximum of their modulus. Now the $\max\{M,1+|a|\}$ gives the right bound.