# How to prove convergence using cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $(a_n)$ be a monotone and bounded sequence such that $a_n \to a$. Let $(b_n)$ be defined as $b_n = (a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n)/n$. I know $(b_n)$ is monotone and bounded, but how do I prove that $b_n \to a$ using the definition of a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Your post would look nicer if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Just some general remarks: 1.) If $(a_n)$ converges, it is redundant to demand that it is bounded. 2.) You can show that $(b_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in order to prove that it converges (assuming you are working in $\mathbb R$), but this way you will not directly be able to say anything about its limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [arithmetic mean of a sequence converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248116/arithmetic-mean-of-a-sequence-converges)

Comment: You cannot prove that $b_n \to a$ using definition of  a Cauchy sequence. Cauchy property can be used to prove convergence but it does not identify the limit.